# bootstrap container fluid table not responsive

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

bootstrap container fluid  table not responsive.i cannot find reason why.Table stands its ground unresponsive.i used an an example My First Bootstrap Page that works fine and is responsive.Understanding bootstrap.I dont want to use scroll but once table is responsive would use css.Using above stylesheet in header
//Looking for collapse horizontal to vertical instead of scroll

```css
//css/bootstrap
      .container, .container-fluid, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
          width: 100%;
          padding-right: 7.5px;
          padding-left: 7.5px;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
  <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           
</div>

<div class="card-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="5%">
                        <col width="13%">
                        <col width="17%">
                        <col width="10%">
                        <col width="30%">
                        <col width="10%">
                        <col width="15%">
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td ><</p></td>
                                <td class="text-right"></td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    
                                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item edit_data" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><span class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></span> Edit</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                        
                                      </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          
          
      </div><div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
        <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
        <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This Class `table-responsive` Table parent

```
<div class="card-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
```

```css
//css/bootstrap
      .container, .container-fluid, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
          width: 100%;
          padding-right: 7.5px;
          padding-left: 7.5px;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
  <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           
</div>

<div class="card-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="5%">
                        <col width="13%">
                        <col width="17%">
                        <col width="10%">
                        <col width="30%">
                        <col width="10%">
                        <col width="15%">
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td ><</p></td>
                                <td class="text-right"></td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    
                                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item edit_data" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><span class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></span> Edit</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                        
                                      </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          
          
      </div><div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
        <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
        <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.Forgot to mention.Looking for collapse horizontal to vertical instead of scroll

Comment: If you see example My First Bootstrap Page.... that works fine